# ASP.NET Regex Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a regular expression that works fine for me when used in ASP.NET Page Routing for URL rewriting.

However, when I try and use it elsewhere in my ASP.NET code it lets past strings that I do not want it to.

My regular expression is,

```
[-_a-zA-Z0-9/]+(\.aspx(\?.+)?)?
```

which is meant to allow strings with files/paths with no extension or with a .aspx file extension, but disallow files/paths with other extensions, eg. "whatever.js".

I am using it unsuccessfully elsewhere in my application like this...

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(pageUrl, @"[-_a-zA-Z0-9/]+(\.aspx(\?.+)?)?"))
```

It seems that as part of the string matches it lets it through. But how can I make sure the entire string (pageUrl) matches?

Comment: Try: `@"^[-_a-zA-Z0-9/]+(.aspx(\?.+)?)?$"`, `^` means "start of the line" and `$` "end of the line".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ^ and $ at the start and end to force it to make the whole string:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(pageUrl, @"^[-_a-zA-Z0-9/]+(.aspx(\?.+)?)?$"))
```

See the MSDN page on ["Anchors in regular expressions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regexUrl = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(" [-_a-zA-Z0-9/]+(.aspx(\?.+)?)?");

check **regexUrl.IsMatch(pageUrl)**

Comment: I had to add a @ in front of the regex string, right? It didn't work, did the same as before.